# ¿Por qué esta función no hace los cálculos correctamente?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

En el DataFrame **df**, tenemos el resutado de una estrategia de inversión. La columna **Position** identifica los puntos de compr (valores 1) y puntos de venta (valores -1).
Queremos añadir columnas a este DataFrame para poder ir viendo la evolución de la inversión. Las columnas son: **['index', 'Data', 'Close', 'Market_returns', 'Position',
'Nº de acciones', 'Dinero disponible', 'Capital total']**
Con esta intención estamos trabajando con la función:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def compra_venta_df(df, initial_investment):
    n_acciones = initial_investment // df.loc[0, 'Close']
    #n_acciones = int(np.floor(n_acciones))  # redondear hacia abajo
    df.loc[0, 'Nº de acciones'] = n_acciones
    df.loc[0, 'Dinero disponible'] = initial_investment - n_acciones * df.loc[0, 'Close']
    df.loc[0, 'Capital total'] = initial_investment

    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        # Compra de acciones
        if df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1:
            n_acciones = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] // df.loc[i, 'Close']
            n_acciones = int(np.floor(n_acciones)) if not np.isnan(n_acciones) else 0 # redondear hacia abajo
            df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = n_acciones
            df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] - n_acciones * df.loc[i, 'Close']
            df.loc[i, 'Capital total'] = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] + df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] * df.loc[i, 'Close']

        # Venta
        if df.loc[i, 'Position'] == -1 :
            dinero_venta = df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] * df.loc[i, 'Close']
            df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] + dinero_venta
            df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = 0
            df.loc[i, 'Capital total'] = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible']
            
    return df


df.reset_index(inplace=True)
initial_investment = 100000
result = compra_venta_df(df, initial_investment)
result
```

Su ejecución devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo cual se puede ver que no es corecto.
¿Dónde está el /los errores?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: ¿No deberías tomar el número de acciones de la operación anterior? es decir la segunda fila que es una venta, tendría que tomar el # de acciones de la compra anterior, es decir: `df.loc[i- 1, 'Nº de acciones']`

Comment: Hola efueyo, si estoy entendiendo bien, es una simulación de compra y venta de acciones, si esto es correcto, falta el precio al que compras la acción y el precio al que la vendes, con esos valores, calculas por un lado, cuantas acciones puedes comprar con tu capital, cuanto dinero te "sobra" y cuanto tienes invertido (Close?), cuantas acciones adquieres, el retorno de cada venta.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que haya un problema en la lógica de la función compra_venta_df. No se están actualizando correctamente las columnas 'Nº de acciones', 'Dinero disponible' y 'Capital total' cuando la posición es 0 (es decir, no se está comprando ni vendiendo). Para solucionar este problema, puedes agregar una cláusula else para manejar el caso en que la posición sea 0. Esta es una posible versión de la función compra_venta_df que debería funcionar correctamente:

```
def compra_venta_df(df, initial_investment):
n_acciones = initial_investment // df.loc[0, 'Close']
df.loc[0, 'Nº de acciones'] = n_acciones
df.loc[0, 'Dinero disponible'] = initial_investment - n_acciones * df.loc[0, 'Close']
df.loc[0, 'Capital total'] = initial_investment

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    # Compra de acciones
    if df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1:
        n_acciones = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] // df.loc[i, 'Close']
        n_acciones = int(np.floor(n_acciones)) if not np.isnan(n_acciones) else 0 # redondear hacia abajo
        df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Nº de acciones'] + n_acciones
        df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] - n_acciones * df.loc[i, 'Close']

    # Venta
    elif df.loc[i, 'Position'] == -1:
        dinero_venta = df.loc[i-1, 'Nº de acciones'] * df.loc[i, 'Close']
        df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] + dinero_venta
        df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = 0
        
    # Sin cambio en posición
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Nº de acciones']
        df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible']
        
    df.loc[i, 'Capital total'] = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] + df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] * df.loc[i, 'Close']

return df
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: No funcina. Compra 10 acciones en la primera posición, para una inversión de 100000€, y en las demás filas de la columna 'Nº de acciones', figuran 0, en posiciones de compra y en posiciones de venta.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado esta solución.

```
# Capital total en cada posición.
import math
import numpy as np

def compra_venta_df(df, initial_investment):
    n_acciones = math.floor(initial_investment / df.loc[0, 'Close'])
    
    df.loc[0, 'Nº de acciones'] = n_acciones
    df.loc[0, 'Dinero disponible'] = initial_investment - n_acciones * df.loc[0, 'Close']
    df.loc[0, 'capital total'] = initial_investment

    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        # Compra de instrumentos
        if df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1:
            n_acciones_temp = math.floor(df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] / df.loc[i, 'Close'])           
            df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = n_acciones
            df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] - n_acciones * df.loc[i, 'Close']
            df.loc[i, 'capital total'] = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] + n_acciones * df.loc[i, 'Close']

        # Venta
        elif df.loc[i, 'Position'] == -1:
            df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible'] + n_acciones * df.loc[i, 'Close']
            df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = 0
            df.loc[i, 'capital total'] = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible']

        # Mantener
        else:
            df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Nº de acciones']
            df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Dinero disponible']
            df.loc[i, 'capital total'] = df.loc[i, 'Dinero disponible'] + df.loc[i, 'Nº de acciones'] * df.loc[i, 'Close']

    return df

df = str_ema.filtered_df_ema.copy(deep=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

initial_investment = 134000

result = compra_venta_df(df, initial_investment)
print(result)
```